# Accessing images in a different project, but in the same solution

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, path, shared-hosting

I made this website for a client which wanted to be able to upload images and then use those images to create some dynamic content on his site. It all works fine, but now I want to isolate that administration part (where he can add images and create his content) on a subdomain.

So at the moment, I have two projects. One where images get uploaded to, and **one who has to access those images** (this is my problem).

I have read multiple topics related to this issue but have not found a solution, I can never get a path outside of my current project.

The only option I am thinking right now that could work is to have some kind of API on the main website, and when an image gets uploaded to the administration site, send that file over to the main site, but that seems pretty overkill knowing that my images will be on the same server.

- Can this be done?
- What is the cleanest/best way to achieve this?

Please note:

- Saving images to the database is not an option. Uploading files on the server and then only storing the path is so much faster.
- My images get uploaded at run-time, I can't use anything that relies on resources/compilation-time.

Thanks!

## UPDATE (SOLUTION)

Rather than saving in the database only the name of the file (image), for example "image1.png" and then trying to retrieve the path in the other project, I ended up saving the absolute URL in the database so that I could then use that URL directly.

```
public static string ResolveServerUrl(string serverUrl, bool forceHttps)
{
  if (serverUrl.IndexOf("://") > -1)
    return serverUrl;

  string newUrl = serverUrl;
  Uri originalUri = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
  newUrl = (forceHttps ? "https" : originalUri.Scheme) +
                "://" + originalUri.Authority + newUrl;
  return newUrl;
}
```

This will give you a URL that looks like `http://yourdomain/path/to/image.jpg`, so you can save it directly in the database and use it as is in the other project.

Comment: Does the "master" **project** have to access the images uploaded from the child project, or does something in the "master" project (html, etc) have just have to be able to link to the images from the child? If the latter, why not have uploads from the child project store file metadata (path, etc) in a db, but the binary content on the file system of the child. And then the master can read from db, build path from db, and reference source in child?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The only option I am thinking right now that could work is to have some kind of API on the main website, and when an image gets uploaded to the administration site, send that file over to the main site

I think you just kind of answered your own question. That is indeed the way to go, or I should say you're on the correct direction towards a enterprise SOA architecture...you are still far from it. But, this is a good start where you start to realize that your system is growing and demanding a more robust architecture

> but that seems pretty overkill knowing that my images will be on the same server.

This is a false statement because if you design it well, you can easily scale out to a different server and platform without affecting your client app(s). Let's say that in the future, the content is moved to its own server, you will only make the pertinent modifications to your "Content Service" while your client apps will not need to be changed at all, they're still pointing to the same endpoint and will never notice what's happening with the internals of the "Contents Service". What this means is that your client apps only care about getting content from the "Contents Service" without knowing where the content is actually hosted, whether in a Windows Server, a Linux server, a Sql Database, an Oracle database, in the US or China. It's not the responsibility of the client app(s) to care about how the content is handled, instead they only need to know how the content is served

Hope it makes sense. I could provide you with some links explaining the absolute benefits of such architectures

Comment: I'll mark this as the correct answer even though I went with a different approach (wasn't worth the time -- for my specific project -- to implement such a solution).